# Tikz: Draw and align with respect to another node

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (c) at (0, 0){};
    \draw[->] (-1, 2)--(1, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I placed the arrow above the circle as centered for I could easily "calculate" the coordinates. Is it possible to produce the same arrow in the manner of: draw a "x cm" line with an arrowhead above of "c"?

I tried `pic` approach but it was needlessly complicated and has limited capabilities with respect to `node` (such a placing label with respect to `pic`). I would think the other approach may be defining an a line with an arrow as a predefined shape (which I am still not good at). Is there any other straightforward approach?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that what you ask for can be achieved simply by storing the radius of the circle in a length and using it in the coordinates of the arrow.

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable for others

Comment: Since you are using a circular node for the circle, you can access coordinates on the circle, for example `(c.north)` etc. The line can be build from these coordinates plus the tikz calc lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more version:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\MyCenterArrow[4][]{%[pass to \draw]{node}{above}{length}
  \draw[->,#1]($(#2)+(-#4/2,#3)$) -- +(#4,0);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=2cm](a){A};
  \MyCenterArrow{a}{2cm}{1cm}
  \node[draw,minimum size=2cm](b) at (3,0) {B};
  \MyCenterArrow{b}{2cm}{3cm}  
  \MyCenterArrow[red]{b}{-2cm}{2cm}
  \MyCenterArrow[green,-latex]{$(a)!0.5!(b)$}{-1.5cm}{2cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A simple `shift` can do the job:

```
\draw[->] ([shift={(-`half length`,`separation`)}]c.north)--++(0:`total length`);
```

Some examples:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
%\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (c) at (0, 0){};
    \draw[->] ([shift={(-1cm,1.5cm)}]c.north)--++(0:2cm);
    \draw[->] ([shift={(-1.5cm,1.2cm)}]c.north)--++(0:3cm);
    \draw[->] ([shift={(-.5cm,.5cm)}]c.north)--++(0:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `calc` library of `tikz` and use `(c.west)` to get the left side of the node and `(c.east)` for the right side. The result is the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] (c) at (0, 0){};
    \draw[->] ($(c.west)+(0,2)$)--($(c.east)+(0,2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that when using a node to draw a circle instead of the `circle` directive, you have to be careful with the value of the `inner sep` (or `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`) propertie, that might screw up the size of the circle. And you can get rid of the `calc` library by using something like `\draw (c.west) ++(0, 2) edge[->] ++(2, 0);`.

Answer (score 2):

This macro draws a circle and an arrow above.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

% #1    x of circle.
% #2    y of circle.
% #3    Radius of circle.
\newcommand{\allyourstuff}[3]{%
    \draw (#1, #2) circle (#3);
    \draw[->] (#1 - #3, #2 + #3 + 2ex) -- ++(2 * #3, 0);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \allyourstuff{1cm}{0cm}{0.5cm}
    \allyourstuff{12mm}{-20mm}{10mm}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]